# AWS CloudWatch logs only showing a single STDOUT output

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-systems-manager

I want to gather some information from my Windows EC2 instances.
I pieced together from searches that I could write a powershell script and have the output directed to CloudWatch logs.
So I created a script and which I launched via Run command AWS-RunPowerShellScript
"Enabled CloudWatch Logs"
I targeted multiple instances.
However when I review the CloudWatch logs I only see the output of one instance (presumably the last one overwrites the former)

Any ideas?

Script:

```
$pvInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | where Name -eq "AWS PV Drivers" | select Name, Version
$pvInfo | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ComputerName" -Force -Value $env:COMPUTERNAME
$pvInfo
```

Sample Output:

I want to see a line for each server, eg..

```
Name           Version ComputerName   
----           ------- ------------   
AWS PV Drivers 8.4.0   SERVERX
AWS PV Drivers 8.2.0   SERVERY
AWS PV Drivers 7.4.0   SMALLSERVER
AWS PV Drivers 8.6.0   ANOTHERSERVER
AWS PV Drivers 6.4.0   EXAMPLESERVER
AWS PV Drivers 8.4.0   BIGSERVER
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, i believe CWL would create a logstream for each instance in the format `CommandID/InstanceID/PluginID` in the log group you specified when configuring/executing the SSM command.

Check the SSM console and look for the execution history - i suspect the command only executed successfully on 1 instance if you only see 1 stream inside the log group level of CWL.

Comment: That's what I thought. But it only creates a log stream for one. I ran it again, this time to a Bucket and CloudWatch. the bucket has a subfolder for each instance with a stdout.txt for each... great. CloudWatch.. only one?

Comment: Check the agent logs on the instances? If SSM console shows it executed on those instances but you dont see their output you should see an error in `c:\programdata\amazon\ssm\logs`. Could be an IAM issue on these instances so its failing to write the logs? (You might need to enable agents debug logs and try command again to get more useful output - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-agent-logs.html)